# Arraylist add object by setter

Tags: java, arraylist

I have created ArrayList and make setter and getter for it.
In the other class i want to add objects in this array. But my code doesn't works. i think i need to add in method setter for array some other code..

```
public class DataVar {

private ArrayList<String> arrayLinks = new ArrayList<>();  

public ArrayList<String> getArrayLinks() {
        return arrayLinks;
    }

    public void setArrayLinks(ArrayList<String> arrayLinks) {
        this.arrayLinks = arrayLinks;
    }
}
```

//Here is another class

```
public class LinksAd {

public void getAllLinksAd() {

DataVar dataVar = new DataVar();
 String link = "href";
 dataVar.setArrayLinks(link) }}
```

Comment: what does not work. please more details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at your code you are trying to add a String type, where your code specifies that you are expecting an ArrayList. Assuming you just want to add a string to your arraylist the following will work:

```
 public void setArrayLinks(String arrayLinks) {
    this.arrayLinks.add(arrayLinks);
}
```

Comment: @J.Doe Please rename this method to `addToArrayLinks` or something similar, because this isn't a setter.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a mehtod to add an Item like this:

```
public void addStringToList(String s)
{
   arrayLinks.add(s); 
}
```

In `LinksAd` you have to wirte:

```
dataVar.addStringToList(link);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement generic setter method.

This is DataVar class:

```
public class DataVar {
    private List<String> itemList=new ArrayList<String>();

    public List<String> getItemlist() {
        return itemList;
    }

    public void setItemList(Object list) {
        if (list.getClass().equals(String.class)) {
            itemList.add((String)list);
        }
        else if (list.getClass().equals(ArrayList.class)) {
            itemList = (ArrayList<String>)list;
        }
        else {
            throw new Exception("Rejected type- You can set String or ArrayList");
        }
    }
}
```

And this is calling setter method example:

Main class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> exampleList = new ArrayList<String>();
    exampleList.add("This example");
    exampleList.add("belongs to");

    String owner = "http://www.javawebservice.com";

    DataVar dataVar = new DataVar();
    dataVar.setItemList(exampleList);
    dataVar.setItemList(owner);

    for(String str:dataVar.getItemlist()){
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
This example  
belongs to  
http://www.javawebservice.com
```

So, you can set ArrayList, also you can set String.